# how to check which file/dir is missing in a partial subversion checkout

Tags: svn

when I run "svnversion -c", I found that this is a partial checkout dir, but how to check which dir is missing? (without a re-checkout)

```
$ svnversion -c
49516:56223P
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [section on Sparse Directories in the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).

```
svn info [DIR]
```

will give you a line `Depth:` telling you the checkout depth of the given `DIR`.

Comment: And 'svn up --set-depth infinity DIR' can then check out the missing pieces.

Comment: `svn up --set-depth infinity` works for me, and `svn info` does not print Depth line, thanks.